# What is the role of "touch" in Asterisk?

Tags: asterisk, voip, pbx, elastix

i tried find role of "touch" in Asterisk but didnt find any answer
What is the role of "touch" in Asterisk?

any role of touch 
tnx

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really asked a good question. Where are you getting "touch" from?

The only think I've ever seen related to touch is feature for call recording.
In features.conf you can uncomment automixmon

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/One-Touch+Features